# How to redirect a specified file extension to other sites using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, request

I need to redirect all files with extension **`.html`** to the same location without the **`.html`** extension. No matter what location it's requested from  For example:

- `/file1.html`   ---> `http:///mysite.com/file1/`
- `/file2.html`   ---> `http:///mysite.com/file2/`
- `/file3.html`   ---> `http:///mysite.com/file3/`
- `/file4.html`   ---> `http:///mysite.com/file4/`

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the following to the `.htaccess` file in the root directory of your site.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ $1/ [L,NC,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)\.html$ http://http:///mysite.com/$1/ [R,L]
```

Comment: `http://http:///`? What is that about? Also there is no need to put the domain there. Just use `RewriteRule ^/?(.+)\.html$ /$1/ [R,L]`